# Save image using ajax in MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I am having this application where I need to upload images, and I am doing so using AJAX.
When I am trying to upload the image using:

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

there is no problem, but when I am trying to use,

```
<input type="button"/>
```

it is causing problem.
In my VIEW, i have something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="OriginalLocation" name="OriginalLocation"/>
```

And this is what I have put in Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveEvent(EventModel viewModel, int? page)

{

int Id = Session["ID"] != null ? UtilityHelper.GetIntegerValue(Session["ID"].ToString()) : 0; //this ID we are fetching from session
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["OriginalLocation"];
viewModel.ContentType = file.ContentType;
Int32 length = file.ContentLength;
byte[] tempImage = new byte[length];
file.InputStream.Read(tempImage, 0, length);
viewModel.ActualImage = tempImage;
// BusinessLayer.Event.BusinessLayer.SetImage(viewModel);
BusinessLayer.Event.BusinessLayer.SaveEvent(viewModel, Id);
EventModel viewmodel = BusinessLayer.TeamEvent.BusinessLayer.GetAllEvents(page, Id);
return View("~/Views/Home/Event.aspx", viewmodel);
}
```

Comment: So that tells us nothing, how are you posting with the second scenario?

Comment: @Gabe, Sorry I forgot to post code. There you go.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload files using AJAX, at least not in older browsers that do not support the [`HTML 5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). If you do not need to support those legacy browsers you could simply use the new `FormData` and `XMLHttpRequest` objects. If on the other hand you need to support legacy browsers you might need to resort to some other techniques such as hidden iframes or Flash movies. For example there are plugins that detect the browser capabilities and based on them will use the correct technique. Take a look at the [`jquery.form plugin`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) or [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Comment: Thanks for informing me that. I was just wasting my time and brain.
I'll see to what you said.